# MVC string and time comparing with <= >=

Tags: linq

I have this "timein" and "timeout" in string format in my database, and I need help because I don't know the logic.

something like this:

```
        Entity.time a;

        using (var b = new Entity.DatabaseEntities())
        {
            a = b.times.Where(v => Convert.ToDateTime(v.timein) <= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm")) && Convert.ToDateTime(v.timeout) >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm"))).FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timein` and `timeout` would be better suited to database type `Time` and .net type `TimeSpan`. Assuming the strings are in the format `HH:mm` you should do a string compare and do not convert anything in your query, that way the query is SARGable. If they are in another format you will have to update the question with some sample data.

The reason your query won't work is because the expression needs to be able to be converted to a SQL statement and not everything (most types/methods actually) are not translatable.

```
Entity.time a;
using (var b = new Entity.DatabaseEntities())
{
    var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    a = b.times.FirstOrDefault(v => 
        string.Compare(v.timein, timeOfDay) >= 0
        && string.Compare(v.timeout, timeOfDay) <= 0);
}
```

For a list of supported canonical methods/functions see [Canonical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/canonical-functions).

See also [string.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) so you understand how that works.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr @Igor for helping me understand the problem